# Tkinter theme is not working, just displays as regular

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, themes

I'm trying to use the theme "sun valley" for a python-based installer that i'm working on. I have all the .tcl files installed and everything should be working, but its not. I even tried to use the built in styles

here's my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os

director = os.path.dirname(__file__)
friendlyName = "python"
file = ""
import shutil
global User

try:
  User = os.getlogin()
except:
  User="home"
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from os import path
path = fr"C:\{User}\AppData\Local\{friendlyName}"

def install():
  try:
    os.mkdir(path)
  except:
    pass
  shutil.copy(file, path)
#E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
window = Tk()
# Just simply import the azure.tcl file
style = ttk.Style(window)
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
window.tk.call('source', os.path.join(dir_path, 'theme\dark.tcl'))
print(os.path.join(dir_path, 'theme\dark.tcl'))
#window.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")
style.theme_use('sun-valley-dark')


window.geometry("600x400")
window.rowconfigure(20)
window.columnconfigure(20)
def askdir():
  direct = filedialog.askdirectory()
  path = direct
  textBox.delete(0, END)
  textBox.insert(0, path)
  #textBox.set(path)
  window.update_idletasks()
window.title(f"{friendlyName} install")
chooseText = Label(window, text=f"choose a place for {friendlyName} to be installed")
chooseText.grid(column=2, row=0)
chooseButton = Button(window, text="choose path", command=askdir)
chooseButton.grid(column=1, row=3)
textBox = Entry(window, text=f"{path}")
textBox.insert(0, path)
textBox.grid(column=2, row=3)
chooseButton = Button(window, text="install", command=install)
chooseButton.grid(column=3, row=4)
chooseButton = Button(window, text="quit", command=window.destroy)
chooseButton.grid(column=1, row=4)
window.mainloop()
```

heres what outputs:

[image: picture of gui]

Comment: You are not using widgets from `ttk`.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `ttk` widgets

instead of `chooseText = Label(window, text=f"choose a place for {friendlyName} to be installed")`

it would be `chooseText =` **ttk**`.Label(window, text=f"choose a place for {friendlyName} to be installed")`

then the style will show up!